# Replace an Array of Objects with a different Array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, spread

I have an Array of Items. Each Item in the Array, has a set of Properties. One of them is called `config: object[]`. It is an array of Objects.

Normally, I provide the full object with the correct `config` array of objects, but for some of my tests, I want to pass different config options. For example `wrong config array`, `empty array` etc..

Here is my code:

```
    const connectionResources = [Array.forEach(object => object.config === [])]
    connectionResources.forEach(builtInOptions => console.log(builtInOptions))
```

This is what I tried. I tried to spread the Array, but no luck there as well.

Can someone help me a little bit here? I basically want my Array of Objects to have an empty config array property instead of the original object.. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to spread the Array, but no luck there as well.

Firstly, if you want to spread an array, you must use the spread operator; e.g. `...myArray`.

> `Array.forEach`

Secondly, `Array.prototype.forEach` **returns** `undefined`, and `Array.forEach` **is** `undefined` (unless you've named your array `Array`, which you shouldn't since that would shadow the `Array` class).

Now to the point, what you need is essentially `Array.prototype.map`

```js
let original = [{a: 3, config: [4, 5], b: 6}, {a: 13, config: [14, 15], b: 16}];

let emptyConfig = original.map(o => ({...o, config: []}));
let hundredConfig = original.map(o => ({...o, config: [100, 101, 102]}));

console.log(original);
console.log(emptyConfig);
console.log(hundredConfig);
```

Answer (score 1):

Example data

```
let resources = [{
    config: [{}, {}]
}, {
    config: [{}, {}]
}];
```

Empty config property

```
resources = resources.map(resource => {
    resource.config = [];
    return resource;
});
```

Comment: Thank you that worked.. One more thing. Is there a way to achieve the same result, with directly mutating the object? I am getting this eslint rule which I can totally disable, `no-param-reassign`, but just asking.

Comment: @DimitrisEfst yes, see my answer